# How to get lineItem information in email receipt using Authorize.net (CIM XML)

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am using Authorize.net CIM XML method to make payment in one of my websites. I have successfully implemented this payment gateway and receiving the email receipt as well.

But the problem is, email receipt doesn't show the itemized information. I have also included the below code for item detail :

```
<lineItems>
  <itemId>ITEM00001</itemId>
  <name>name of item sold</name>
  <description>Description of item sold</description>
  <quantity>1</quantity>
  <unitPrice>6.95</unitPrice>
  <taxable>true</taxable>
</lineItems>
<lineItems>
   <itemId>ITEM00002</itemId>
   <name>name of other item sold</name>
   <description>Description of other item sold</description>
   <quantity>1</quantity>
   <unitPrice>1.00</unitPrice>
   <taxable>true</taxable>
</lineItems>
```

So can someone help me out ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011971/authorize-net-xml-adding-line-items

Comment: @RST: This link doesn't solve my issue. I need to show lineitems in email.

Comment: what does your complete email code look like?

Comment: Authorize.net sends email automatically when order is successful. We just use authorize.net CIM XML code to generate all order detail. There is no specific email code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the merchant receipt, it will never include the line item details.  Instead, you will need to use the transaction details api or login to the merchant interface to access that information.

For customer email receipts, you can configure those in the Merchant Interface or through the API: http://goo.gl/bGHX9X

Comment: I agree, but if I use transaction detail api then I will have to send email receipt to the customer manually. I want that item information should be sent with the email which is sent as default somehow.

Comment: You can read more about sending email receipts to customers here: http://goo.gl/bGHX9X

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I checked this link and also checked the email receipt option under settings but it only enables or disables the email receipt to be sent to the customers. It doesn't provide any method to send line itmes into that email receipt. The email receipt is already being sent to customer at my end but I want to include lineitmes into that email receipt.